# Getting ID of div from string using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hello In a foreach loop in jquery I am getting a div element/html in the form of string. So in this string I am getting a a div like this `<div id="div1"> Some text</div>` Now I want the Id of this div but I am confused how to get it from string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call `$` on it, then get the `id` attribute:

```js
const str = `<div id="div1"> Some text</div>`;
console.log($(str).attr('id'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the string is untrustworthy, this will allow for arbitrary execution of JS, which is bad - use DOMParser instead:

```js
const str = `<div id="div1"> Some text</div>`;
const domDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
console.log(domDocument.querySelector('[id]').id);
```